# How to can I upload a form on django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to make a matchmaking project on python django such as snapchat's hoop, but first I am trying to do the easiest part(what I know) which is just making the user create a profile to find a mate and then show that created profile to the other users, currently I am not using any matchmaking based on questions, I need to first show the created user to other users. The error comes when I pass the variables to the html via for loops, and now the mates.html file doesnt show anything. Please if you need more explanation let me know in the comments.

models.py (Profile model show the profile of the user which is created by default wen the user is created and Mates model shows the profile that the user has to create which provide an image and a description)

```
    class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        bio = models.CharField(max_length=400, default=1, null=True)

    class Mates(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user")
        users_requests = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="users_requests")
        req_bio = models.CharField(max_length=400)
        req_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='requestmates_pics', null=True, blank=True, default=False)
```

views.py

```
    def matesmain(request):
        contents = Mates.objects.all()
        args123 = {
           'contents': contents,
        }
        return render(request, 'mates.html', args123)

    def mates(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form_mates = MatesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form_mates.is_valid():
                instance = form_mates.save(commit=False)
                instance.user = request.user
                instance.save()
                return redirect('mates-main')
                print('succesfully uploded')
        else:
            form_mates = MatesForm()
            print('didnt upload')
        return render(request, 'mates.html', {'form_mates': form_mates})
```

forms.py

```
    class MatesForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Mates
            fields = ('req_bio', 'req_image',)
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('mates', views.mates, name='mates'),
        path('mates-main', views.matesmain, name='mates-main'),
    ]
```

mates.html

```
    <div class="mates">
                <div class="mates-container">
                    {% for content in contents %}
                    <div class="mates-item"><a href="{% url 'profile' username=content.user.username %}" style="float: left">{{ content.user }}</a> 
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <div class="mates-item">content(picture)
                        <form action="{% url 'mates' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ form_mates.as_p }}
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'doess not show anything'? does it produce any error?

Comment: @mursalin no, It doesnt produce any error, it just doesnt show the information on the page, everything inside the for loops doesnt show up

Comment: can you confirm your 'matesthing' and 'content' in not empty?

Comment: @mursalin What do you mean?

Comment: @mursalin Well I think that the code should work on the html I dont see the error there, please correct me if I am wrong. On the matesmain view I am passing those variables to the html I think.

Comment: If there were any error django would have reported the error. I suspect your query result is empty.

Comment: @mursalin let me see if I can fix it

Comment: Is your indent correct in the views.py snippet? There should be indent after if statement for example.

Comment: @BrankoRadojevic How can I add that?

Comment: @mursalin It didnt make it work, can you help me?

Comment: After if statement python requires indent (or indentation, 4 spaces) to  differentiate block of code that has to be executed. The code in view.py after the if request.method == 'POST': is correctly indented, but code after if form_mates.is_valid(): is not, at least in code that you copied here.

Comment: @BrankoRadojevic ok I changed that but now I still have the same error

Comment: So, you are trying to open /mates url and you don't get anything? I am a little bit confused because both views actually use same template, and the second one is not feeding anything to it?

Comment: @BrankoRadojevic I just updated my question, now it passes the form and it is working now but when I try to show users username, it just doesnt show up. Is it because I havent submit the form?

Comment: I see that Michael gave the answer where I was heading. Good it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are displaying the form with the second function (mates), then you aren't sending any context for your fields to iterate over. Try like so:

```
def mates(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form_mates = MatesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form_mates.is_valid():
                instance = form_mates.save(commit=False)
                instance.user = request.user
                instance.save()
                return redirect('mates-main')
                print('succesfully uploded')
        else:
            form_mates = MatesForm()
            print('didnt upload')
        context = {
           'form_mates': form_mates,
           'contents': Mates.objects.all()
        }
        return render(request, 'mates.html', context)
```

and in your other view (matesmain):

```
contents = Mates.objects.all()
        args123 = {
           'contents': contents,
           'form_mates': MatesForm()
        }
        return render(request, 'mates.html', args123)
```

I'm not sure I understand, however, why you have two separate views for this.

Comment: Thank you Michael! Do you have any idea of how can I add questions in which a user can find a mate based on if both have the same answer? for example snapchat's hoop finds people from the gender(male, female) and region to match up with you.

Comment: Please I have no idea how I can do that and there is nothing on youtube from what i have searched for.

Comment: You can do that, but it is a bit more complicated - you can use tags or text fields and store the results. If you are using Postgres, you can do a document search that pull out keywords. Lots of ways to do it, but it takes a bit of work.

Comment: Hey michael, I havent thought of using tags thats a good idea;)